# Sending some data through Link component in React

Tags: react-redux, reactjs

Is it possible to send data through  Component in react js.

I have a react component: On load of this component I have an api call and get a response,  on this component I have this

Go to Next Page

On this Next page load I need some data from response of my previous component - how do I send it? is there a way to do this in react?

Comment: not sure how to do this? somewhere in the state of next component i need to set this? but how to propagate?

Comment: The best solution is to adapt to architectures like [Flux](https://github.com/facebook/flux)  or [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) which would allow you to have separate state objects change it and pass changes to different components

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any kind of state management framework such as redux or flux, you can set the data in the store once the api call is fullfilled (on your first page, ie the one with the `Go to next page` link). Now on the next Page, you will have the data you need in the store which you can retrieve and do whatever you want with.